# jQuery local web storage

Tags: jquery, html

How can I make local web storage with jQuery, that when my web is visited the number goes up like on the example below?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     if( localStorage.hits ){
        localStorage.hits = Number(localStorage.hits) +1;
     }

     else{
        localStorage.hits = 1;
     }
     document.write("Total Hits :" + localStorage.hits );
  </script>

  <p>Refresh the page to increase number of hits.</p>
  <p>Close the window and open it again and check the result.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't provide any API to access local storage (see [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/?s=storage)).

Just use the `localStorage` API, what you are already seem to be doing.